What is the name of this "Repetitious" movie?
Years ago, I watched a movie which had a different subject. In this movie, everything were repetitious and as far as I know, the main character was a Girl. In one scene this girl tried to kill herself as another character in a ship (She didn't know that she was the same one who tried to kill) and in another scene, I can remember that there was a place full of dead birds because thing happens repetitiously an each bird died in other times.

While your movie has already been correctly identified with 99.9% certainty, please don't forget to mention all the details you might remember, including how many "years ago", when the movie was likely from (even if just a rough guess), where it was likely from, or any other meta or plot details.

@NapoleonWilson Ok, I will :)

You're clearly looking for the movie Triangle:

When Jess sets sail on a yacht with a group of friends, she cannot shake the feeling that there is something wrong. Her suspicions are realized when the yacht hits a storm and the group is forced to board a passing ocean liner to get to safety, a ship Jess is convinced she's been on before. The ship appears deserted, the clock on board has stopped, but they are not alone... Someone is intent on hunting them down, one by one. And Jess unknowingly holds the key to end the terror.

It is later revealed that Jess is trapped in a time loop experiencing the same events over and over, though from different perspectives, being effectively the same person who hunts down the people, but from a different interation of the loop. There's also the scene with all the dead birds from all the previous loop iterations.

Thank you so much, this was what I exactly looked for. a question, asking about movie names wont break this Q&A sites rules?

@AmirrezaNasiri "asking about movie names wont break this Q&A sites rules?" - No, movie identification questions are currently on-topic here, as evident from the many of them already asked.
